# What JQuery Plugin is being used here?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, imagemap, zooming, seadragon

I found this brilliant image map plugin on the BBC here: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-18295433

The highlighted links are essentially normal  tags which have had their position set to absolute to hover them in different places on the image. Then they are using a javascript plugin file to zoom into areas on the image depending on which  tag is clicked. The javascript plugin file is here: http://node1.bbcimg.co.uk/glow/glow/map.1.7.7.js

However I can't find an open source version anywhere. Does anyone know of anything similar or what this plugin is actually called?

Comment: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/ perhaps.

Comment: Hi @Blazemonger, thanks I saw this one too with a bit of googling but it doesn't do the zoom in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is using Microsoft's Deep Zoom - [Seadragon Ajax](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/gg413360).

The [**SeaDragon**](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/SeadragonAjax) component also comes with [ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Seadragon/Seadragon.aspx).

It's currently licensed under an [open-source compatible BSD license](https://getsatisfaction.com/livelabs/topics/seadragon_ajax_license).